# TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, soap

I have just started to learn soap client with Node.Out of the available packages to this, I have decided to go with easy-soap npm package [here](https://github.com/moszeed/easysoap) to make soap call in Nodejs.

First attempt ends up with the error. What am I doing wrong here ?
How to take it forward from here. Can someone shed light on this ?

```js
(function() {

    "use strict";

        var easysoap = require('easysoap');

// ##define soap params

      var params = {
                host   : '190.100.00.00',
                path   : '/webservices/angular2/',
                wsdl   : '/webservices/angular2/php-server.wsdl',

                // set soap headers (optional)
                headers: [{
            'name'     : 'item_name',
            'value'    : 'item_value',
            'namespace': 'item_namespace'
        }]
    }


//  ##create the client


  var soapClient = easysoap.createClient(params);



// ##get all available functions

                soapClient.getAllFunctions()
                .then((functionArray) => { console.log(functionArray); })
                        .catch((err) => { console.error(err); });


}
```

```
 **ERROR:**
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined
at doGetRequest.then (/home/user/test/node_modules/wsdlrdr/src/index.js:326:41)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

Comment: What is the error and where do you get it? Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: @Skyler I am executing this in node server. I have posted the errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of the available packages ., it is better to use strong-soap [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/strong-soap) and there are no errors anymore.

```
"use strict";

var soap = require('strong-soap').soap;

var url = 'http://192.100.00.000/webservices/angular2/php-server.wsdl';

var requestArgs = {
symbol: 'IBM'
};

var options = {};

soap.createClient(url, options, function(err, client) {

var method = client['check_username'];

method(requestArgs, function(err, result, envelope, soapHeader) {

console.log('Response Envelope: \n' + envelope);
console.log('Result: \n' + JSON.stringify(result));

});
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `.catch((err) => { throw new Error(err); });`,

do `.catch(err => console.error(err); )` which can check the stacktrace and see which line the error comes from.

If it is a library issue, file a new issue on their [Github Repo](https://github.com/moszeed/easysoap/issues).

Also please remove the Typescript tag.

Comment: Sorry for the misplaced tag. I have changed it. Thank you